# The usage of "Open"

Tags: word-usage

As I know, "Open" can be used as a Verb or an Adjective

For example, we say ***I'm opening the door***, but do we say ***The door is opening*** ?

Comment: Yes, particularly if it is an automatic door.

Comment: You begin the question asking about *open*, but then ask about *opening*. *The door is opening* means something different from *The door is open* and from *The door is an opening*.

Comment: I'm sure most people would say it's a ***verb*** usage in *The door is **opening***. But the present participle *can* be used in an unquestionably adjectival role - as in, say, *I asked the glazier to fit me an **opening** window in my bathroom*.

Answer (score 1):

The door is open. That is the state or condition of the door.
The door is opening. The door is in the process of becoming open.

When the door is finished opening, it will then be open.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right, *open* can be either an adjective or a verb. But that's not the issue, it's a matter of transitivity of the verb.

Open is an [Ergative](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergative_verb) verb, it can be either transitive or intransitive depending on the context. So that means, both sentences are correct, just the difference is the latter doesn't answer *"Who opens the door?"* question. And I agree with Willow Rex in his comment that he said it's particularly used if it's an automatic door.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *open* can be a verb, and *opening* is the form of the verb called the [present participle](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participle.htm).  The present participle is used like an adjective with an auxiliary verb ("is", in this case) to indicate its current status or activity.

And as user178049 points out, *to open* can be used either transitively or intransitively, so it's correct to say either

- I am *opening* the door (I am performing the action of making the door open)
- The door is *opening* (the door is performing the action of becoming open)